# SQL/MX Insert With Timestamp

Tags: sqlmx

Does anyone know how to insert with a timestamp this is on an HP Tandem SQL/MX system. I HAVE SEEN THE FUNCTION CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BUT IT COMES BACK WITH AN ERROR.

```
insert into =BOXTABLE
values (71,'A',1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'123456');
```

Example:

```
>>BEGIN WORK; 
>>insert into =BOXINSTANT 
+>values 
+>(71,'A',1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,' 174520870009');
```

> *** ERROR from SQL [-4089]: The value list of the INSERT statement cannot reference a column. ***

Comment: `>>BEGIN WORK;`
`>>insert into =BOXINSTANT`
`+>values`
`+>(71,'A',1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,' `174520870009');`
`*** ERROR from SQL [-4089]: The value list of the` 
`INSERT statement cannot reference a column. ***`

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with SQLMX but a typical sql statement requires you to list the fields and then the values as such:

```
Insert Into BOXTABLE ('Fieldname1', 'Fieldname2','Fieldname3','Fieldname4')
Values (71,'A',1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'123456');
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977880(v=vs.71).aspx